# Regex - Why doesn't this pattern work when using the new RegExp method?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm searching this string for an the 'invite=XXXX' part. I am using a capturing group to extract the value between '=' and ';'. When I use the first regex method it works, but when I use the second it doesn't. **Why is this?**

```
var string = "path=/; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; invite=1323969929057; path=/; expires=Sat, 14 Jan 2012 17:25:29 GMT;";

// first method
var regex1 = /invite=(\w+)/;
var regexMatch1 = string.match(regex1);

// second method
var regex2 = new RegExp("/invite=(\w+)/");  
var regexMatch2 = string.match(regex2);

// log results
console.log(regexMatch1);
console.log(regexMatch2);
```

[**Working example here >>**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkQ9/5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the `\` and like Jake said, remove the slashes.

```
var regex2 = new RegExp("invite=(\\w+)");  
                                  ^ Notice 2 "\"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqkQ9/10/

Comment: That is still logging 'null' in my console (Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

When you use the RegExp() constructor, the slashes are not needed.  Change to this:

```
var regex2 = new RegExp("invite=(\\w+)");
```

Comment: You may also need to escape the backslash, as Daniel suggested

Answer (score 2):

Because the `/` is for a regex literal. Since you are using the `RegExp` object, you need to remove the slashes. You also need to escape the backslash since you aren't using a literal:

```
var regex2 = new RegExp("invite=(\\w+)");  
var regexMatch2 = string.match(regex2);
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
 var regex2 = new RegExp("invite=(\\w+)");
```

Regular expressions in string form have no `/` prefix and postfix and all escape characters must have `\\` instead of `\`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the slashes while creating RegExp object using `RegExp`.

If you want, you can even compare the patterns using RegExp.source

Try `console.log(regex1.source === regex2.source)`

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0):

remove the /'s from the RegExp constructor, scape the \w and put the second parameter:

```
var regex2 = new RegExp("invite=(\\w+)", "");
```